# Finding if a date is in the Future or in the Past

Tags: vba, date

```
'checks to see if date is within x days of the inputted date
Function isFutureDate(x) As Boolean   
    Dim daysFuture As Integer
    Dim futureDate As Date
    daysFuture = Sheet1.Range("e1").Value - 1
    'we have to add one to not count today
    futureDate = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, daysFuture) 
    If x >= Date And x < futureDate Then
        isFutureDate = True
    Else
        isFutureDate = False
    End If
End Function
```

---

```
'checks to see if date is in the past x days
Function isPastDate(x) As Boolean   
    Dim BDate As Date
    Dim y As Date
    Dim daysPast As Integer
    'subtract one to not count today
    daysPast = Sheet1.Range("E1").Value - 1 'subtract one to not count today

    BDate = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1 * daysPast)
    If x < Date And x > BDate Then
        isPastDate = True
    Else
        isPastDate = False
    End If
End Function
```

These are the two functions I have currently. `x` is passed as a **Date**. When I step through the program, I notice an error with `BDate` in the `isPastDate function`. In my file, I have a cell where the user enters how many days in the future they would like to see entries for. I think this is where my main problem is. When I check the value of daysFuture or daysPast I get 0 while the user entered value is clearly 7.

Comment: Is X an integer, date or variant data type?  '7' is not a date.

Comment: Have you tried DateDiff() function?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't follow. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to determine if the inputted date "x" is within y days of the value in Cell e7 in Sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 'checks to see if date is within x days of the inputted date
    Function isFutureDate(x As Date) As Boolean
        Dim xDays As Integer
        Dim xFuture As Integer
        xDays = Sheet1.Range("E1").Value
        xFuture = DateDiff("d", Date, x)
        If xFuture > xDays Then
            isFutureDate = True
        Else
            isFutureDate = False
        End If
    End Function
    'checks to see if date is in the past x days
    Function isPastDate(x As Date) As Boolean
        Dim xDays As Integer
        Dim xPast As Integer
        xDays = Sheet1.Range("E1").Value
        xPast = DateDiff("d", Date, x)
        If xPast < xDays Then
            isPastDate = True
        Else
            isPastDate = False
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: Try the above code if you are checking x (as date) is future or past within y days in Cell E1..

Comment: Just make sure x value entered is always in a date format.